# Is it easier to understand to modify this expression "as commonly we want to" as "as we commonly want to"?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bee/courses/scribe/lec_08_28_2013.pdf) says

> In this lecture, we introduce and formalize methods for building classifiers, and provide intuitive guidelines
>   for the selection of priors. The classification problem is ubiquitous in the sciences, as commonly we want to
>   infer scientifically meaningful labels based on easily obtainable features of the data.

at the first looking, "as commonly" makes me think there is another part, with which the whole thing could be "as commonly ... as".

is it my bad intuition?

or

this expression could be reasonably modified to "as we commonly want to"?

Answer (score 1):

The word "as" means "because" or "since" here.  It would be better to replace it with "since" to avoid this sort of misreading.  You could also say "as we commonly want to" or, equivalently, "since we commonly want to".